# Dynamic Table with Rowspan PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I have data like this:

| ID | Parts Number | Parts Name | Std Qty | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9810001 | NGK-11O7GGH | 12 | 10 |
| 1 | 9810010 | NGK-1187GGH | 12 | 10 |
| 2 | 3810001 | OVH-78GH | 14 | 16 |
| 2 | 4810010 | OVH-86GS | 14 | 16 |

So, each ID can have many parts variant, but user only set the stock for each ID not each variant.
Then, the table should be look like this:

[Table with rowspan in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sMPU.png)

How i can dynamically make this table with PHP and MySQL?
So i can export to excel correctly.

My Code:

```
<?php
$pit = 10;
if($pit<=6){
    $std = 'usix';
}elseif($pit>=7 || $pit<=10){
    $std = 'sevten';
}if($pit>10){
    $std = 'tenplus';
}
$inv = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT i.*, s.$std AS std FROM inventory i, sparepart s WHERE id_dealer='1' AND s.id_parts=i.id_parts");
?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Part Number</th>
                    <th>Deskripsi</th>
                    <th>Std Qty</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        $i = 1;
                        
                        while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($inv)){
                            $id = $d['id_parts'];
                            $varian = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM varian WHERE id_parts='$id'");
                            $varian2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM varian WHERE id_parts='$id'");
                            if($d['stock']>$d['std']){
                                $status = 'STOCK AMAN';
                                $class = 'text-success';
                            }elseif($d['stock']<$d['std']){
                                $status = 'STOCK LOW';
                                $class = 'text-danger';
                            }
                            echo "
                                <tr>
                                    <td>$i</td>
                                    <td style='padding:0'>";
                                while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($varian)){
                                    echo "
                                    <p class='mb-0 p-1'>$x[part_number]</p><hr>"
                                    ;
                                }
                                echo "</td><td style='padding:0'>";
                                while($y=mysqli_fetch_array($varian2)){
                                    echo"
                                    <p class='mb-0 p-1'>$y[nama_var]</p><hr>
                                    ";
                                }
                            echo
                                    "</td>
                                    <td>$d[std]</td>
                                    <td>$d[stock]</td>
                                    <td class='$class'>$status</td>
                                </tr>
                            ";
                            $i++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have had need to do something very similar for various business projects where the recordsets were often quite large and in all honesty I found it much simpler to export the complete recordset from the db and use VB within Excel to create a macro do format the output nicely